# Looking For an Opensource Project C#

Tags: c#, open-source

I've looked on SourceForge's help wanted... there seems to be nothing for a C# developer. I'm just looking for a project to get my hands dirty with a bunch of different things.  Any one have a project they know of?

Comment: MbUnit has a chance to compete with MSFT ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the popular open source C# project.(not all from sourceforge.net). you can also check [codeplex.com](http://www.codeplex.com) for more projects.

[Sharp Develop](http://www.codeplex.com/SharpDevelop)

[NHibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/428.html)

[Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/)

[Rhino Mocks](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx)

[Mono](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html/)

[ASP.NET MVC Framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc/)

[.Net Framework Source Code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx)

[The Weekly Source Code](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CategoryView.aspx?category=Source%2BCode)(Scott Hanselman's Series)

[Microsoft's Pattern and Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

- Mono
- NHibernate
- Castle
- [From CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?projectSearchText=C%23)

I'll have a few more.

Answer (score 3):

Most open source projects don't advertise for help.

They just accept patches from the community.

Why not pick one of your favourites and add some useful functionality?

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 3):

You may find fiddling with [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/) ([hosted on code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/)) entertaining. It's just an example among MANY other existing projects out there.

Or have a look at projects hosted on http://www.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

SourceForge doesn't seem to have that many C# projects.

I don't have any specific projects to suggest.  That said, you might want to check on http://www.codeplex.com/ since that's Microsoft's own open-source site, so there's going to be a lot more stuff there aimed at C# developers.  I would hope you could find something that fits your interests there and contribute to it.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try [ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/)'s [search by language](http://www.ohloh.net/p?sort=users&q=language%3Acsharp).

Answer (score 1):

As it happens, Stack Overflow maintains [a list of OS projects looking for development help](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/all). There are some C# projects there.